# Unknown entity: java.lang.Class with Hibernate 5.3

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am new to hibernate and I have seen many ways of creating the util for Hibernate. I think that is where my error is but I am unsure. (Using Oracle 12c and Hibernate 5.3). My goal is to try to test the ability of hibernate to store a table into a database (oracle). The things I am concerned about are the hibernateUtil and if that is correct/ hibernate.cfg.xml is correct on the mappings/ if folder structure is correct for a web application servlet/ and if my Requirements Bean annotations is correct. I have looked at other posts but they all pointed to the entity import issue which I fixed. Thank you for your help.

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Class
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.entityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:670)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1721)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:118)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:705)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:700)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:350)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.save(Unknown Source)
at com.hibernate.DAO.Requirement.addRequirement(Requirement.java:27)
at com.hibernate.DAO.Requirement.main(Requirement.java:40)
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">*******</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:TCS</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">TCS</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl">create</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</property>
    <mapping class="com.hibernate.beans.Requirements"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Requirements.java** (I did not include the getters and setters, since they are not needed)

```
package com.hibernate.beans;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Requirements {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
   @Column(name="REQ_ID")
   private long REQ_ID;

   @Embedded
   @Basic
   @Column(name="Full_Name", nullable=false)
   private Name name;

   @Basic
   @Column(name= "Account", nullable=false)
   private String account;

   @Basic
   @Column(name= "Skills_Needed", nullable=false)
   private String skillsNeeded;

   @Basic
   @Column(name= "Pending_Requirement", nullable=false)
   private int pendingRequirement;

   @Basic
   @Column(name= "Status", nullable=false)
   private String status;
 }
```

**Requirement.Java**

```
package com.hibernate.DAO;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import com.hibernate.beans.Name;
import com.hibernate.beans.Requirements;
import com.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil;

public class Requirement {

    private static void addRequirement() {
     Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Requirements re = new Requirements();
            re.setName(new Name("Bob", "Steven"));
            re.setAccount("Verizon");
            re.setPendingRequirement(2);
            re.setStatus("Pending");
            re.setSkillsNeeded("C++");
            session.save(Requirements.class);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Requirement re = new Requirement(sessionFactory);
        addRequirement();
    }
 }
```

**Folder Structure**

[image: Folder]

Comment: Updated the Requirement.java to just call it and get the current session and still getting the same error

Comment: Actually, I think I forgot to add the actual object woops. Let me try a few things

Comment: Now I am getting this. Hibernate: select REQ_ID_SEQENCE.nextval from dual
Hibernate: insert into TCS.Requirements (REQ_ID) values (?)
Sep 21, 2019 9:30:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Sep 21, 2019 9:30:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch performExecution
ERROR: HHH000315: Exception executing batch [java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: @whats the name of your table in oracle